# numpy/pandas: test float64 arrays are equal up to significant digits

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

I have two pandas data frames in which I store money amounts, i.e. decimal numbers with at most 15 significant decimal digits. Since float64 has a precision of 15 significant decimal digits, this should be lossless.

**How do I compare the values of two such dataframes for equivalence up to the 15 significant decimal digits?**

In short, I am looking for something like [numpy.testing.assert_approx_equal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_approx_equal.html) - which should however take numpy arrays as arguments rather than only scalars.

Another option would be to use a rounding function that can round to a given number of significant decimal digits rather than the usual decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

there's actually a numpy function for this:

```
np.allclose
```

definition/usage:

```
np.allclose(a, b, rtol=1e-05, atol=1e-08)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is what I am looking for: "allclose(a,b) might be different from allclose(b,a)". This is not quite right...

Comment: yeah, just set the rtol to 0.0 and that will make that not the case